# Jquery function for paste

Tags: java

paste only characters using j query if I'm pasting abc123 output would be abc.i have same function but this paste only numeric value like if i'm paste abc123 output is 123

```
$('.nopaste').bind('paste', function() {
    var el = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Ok. What's your question then?

Comment: if I'm pasting abc123 output would be abc.i want this output from jquery function

Comment: To only match the letters in the string, simply replace the `/\D/g` regex with `/[a-z]/ig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for character only will be

```
el.value.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '');
```